# Confusing "approve edit" display

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

I was just notified of an edit to a post I made, and requested to review it.

Having not done this in a long time, it took me awhile to find the review link, but I got past that.  The edit looked fine to me, so I was expecting to find an "approve" button.

The display I saw showed 3 other users had approved the edit  *but it wasn't obvious that the edit had been accepted* (at least, not to me).    The display offered a "Next" button, but not an "approve" button.  In my confusion, I guessed I had to press "Next" (next what?) to get to the "Approve" opportunity, and sure enough, when I did so, I was offered an "Approve" button.

So I did.  And then got told I wasn't paying attention, that I had approved a vandalized post (not my post).

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2406891

Guess in fact, that's what I did, but the interface I think led me astray.

I think the review page should show clearly that the edit was approved and that it isn't possible to approve it more.  I can't see that page now, so I don't know if it did say that somewhere.   Clearly it wasn't red or blinky enough.

Another possible fix is to change the NEXT button to say  "Review a different message edit?"

Answer (score 1):

Taking away the action buttons and adding an entire blob at the start showing both what action was taken as well as who voted for what, is all rather distinctive.  This doesn't appear to be a common problem that many people seem to have.  Your proposed changes are completely over the top and would be more disruptive than helpful.

Comment: I didn't suggest taking away the action buttons.  I suggested making it clearer, somehow, that the approval action was no longer an option, and that the NEXT button was clear about NEXT what.  (I find your tone of response a bit over the top.)

Comment: @IraBaxter I know you're not suggesting taking away the action buttons.  I'm telling you that the action buttons are already being taken away, and that that's one of the means of conveying to the user that the post cannot be acted on.

Comment: It may be obvious to someone that has used the interface that those actions were not available.  To those of us that haven't seen the interface, it is clear that that actions aren't available, but it is NOT clear that those actions aren't possible and you just have to look in some funny place.  Which I did, and was rewarded with what I expected, but it wasn't what I thought it was.  I'd expect other non-experts to get surprised the same way.  It may be that isn't worth fixing in an economic sense, but I'm a little peeved that a mistake any newbie could make got me a hand slap and a bad rep.

Comment: @IraBaxter The primary mistake that you made, that most others don't seem to make, is that once you clicked `next`, you didn't look at anything else on the page at all, you just immediately went and clicked an action button.  Had you looked around much at all it would be clear you were on a completely new review.  That said, I also don't see many people being confused as to what "next" means.  You're the first person I've heard of to have found the button confusing.

Comment: Experts are always surprised by what newbies do.  My expectations were set to see an "Approve" button (since I liked the edit, the edit appeared to require my approval, and it wasn't obviously done; what else could possibly happen next?), I was NOT expecting to see another message edit to approve (no experience with the UI).  You can chalk this up to inexperienced users.  I chalk it up to expectations the UI set by not being clear.  ... we've bantered enough; Meta has heard my remark. If it doesn't happen to anybody else, then we're done.  If not, you have a bit of history.